# Mockito.verify selective methods call

Tags: mockito, verify, invocation

In my application, I have code that looks like -

```
request.setParameter("a",false);//line1
request.setParameter("b",someObject);//line2
request.setParameter("c",someObject);//line3
request.setParameter("d",someObject);//line4
```

I have mocked the request object and now I want to verify if the line3 was invoked or not. I do not care about the other lines, in the test class I tried-
    `Mockito.verify(request).setParameter("c",someObject)` , however I get error -

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
request.setParameter("c",com.test.MyObject@fec107);
-> at XXX

Actual invocation has different arguments:
request.setParameter("a", false);
```

For some reason, Mockito compares the first invocation and throws error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mockito will only do that if the invocation that you're verifying did NOT in fact happen.  So if `request.setParameter("c", someObject)` had been called, your test would pass, regardless of the other calls.  If a `verify` fails, Mockito tries to be helpful by identifying calls that were a "near miss" to the one that you tried to verify; but *only* if the `verify` fails.